# Removing NSNull from Key Path Results with Partial Matches

Tags: ios, nsobject, foundation, key-value-coding

Given a data structure with mismatching objects:

```
 1> import Foundation
 2> let d: NSDictionary = ["test": [["name": "Dick", "age": 101], ["name": "Jane"]]]
```

`valueForKeyPath:` will return the values for the total number of sub-objects:

```
 3> d.valueForKeyPath("test.name") as! NSArray
 $R2: NSArray = "2 values" {
   [0] = "Dick"
   [1] = "Jane"
 }
```

Even when the leaf key doesn't exist in all cases:

```
4> d.valueForKeyPath("test.age") as! NSArray 
$R3: NSArray = "2 values" {
  [0] = Int64(101)
  [1] = {
    NSObject = {
     isa = NSNull
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some way to only get the existing `age`s, without an instances of `NSNull`?

`@distinctUnionOfArrays` and so on helps if there are multiple sub-objects without the leaf key, but you're still left with the one `NSNull`.

On a somewhat side note, if the leaf key is entirely unknown, then only `NSNull`s are returned:

```
5> d.valueForKeyPath("test.dog") as! NSArray
$R4: NSArray = "2 values" {
  [0] = {
    NSObject = {
      isa = NSNull
    }
  }
  [1] = {
    NSObject = {
      isa = NSNull
    }
  }
}
```

In contrast, if the root key is unknown, `nil` is returned:

```
6> d.valueForKeyPath("dog.name")
$R5: AnyObject? = nil
```

This logic strikes me as inconsistent, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

var array:[AnyObject] = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, NSNull(),1.7, 1.8, 1.9]

let newArr = array.filter{ !($0 is NSNull) }

newArr

Comment: I know how to do it in normal code. I'm specifically asking about key path logic.

Comment: you can extend NSObject  with your function  valueForKeyPath logic?

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question doesn't make sense to me:

This code:

```
let x = d.valueForKeyPath("dog.name")
```

Makes x an optional `AnyObject?`.

It returns nil with the key "dog.name" on your data. That's different than an array with nil/NSNULL entries.

If you try to force-unwrap it, it crashes:

```
let x = d.valueForKeyPath("dog.name") as! NSArray
```

If you want to get rid of the NSNull entries, use a filter:

```
let y = (d.valueForKeyPath("test.age") as? NSArray)?.filter{!($0 is NSNull)}
```

In the above code, I use `as?` to cast the result of `valueForKeyPath` to an array so it can return nil if the call does not return any results. (Otherwise it crashes.)

I then only call filter if the results are not nil.

Finally, I filter the array to only those objects that are not NSNull.

Note that y is an optional, and will be nil if d.valueForKeyPath("test.age") does not return a result.